# how to discuss the convergence of this series according to $\alpha$ (variable) $\sum\limits_2^n\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\alpha}+(-1)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> how to discuss the convergence of this series according to $\alpha$ (variable) $\sum\limits_2^n\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\alpha}+(-1)^n}$

I already proved its convergence when $\alpha >1$ but I couldn't for $0⩽ \alpha ⩽1$ and $\alpha <0$ although I thought about using alternating series I'm not sure about it.

Comment: the question is not cleal what is the index of the series